# Color formatting for the running balance in rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Actually I have running balance in my statement and it reflects with colour that is when balance is positive it is black and when balance goes negative it becomes red.

I would like to have same formatting to be applied when running balance is out of the statements table.

Right now it shows '-' sign for negative values but I want to have to be in red colour without '-' negative sign.

Please refer the screen-shot for better understanding as shown below;

[image: screenshot.png]

Running balance inside the table body;

```
<tr>
<% @balance += xvaziri.amount.to_f - xvaziri.discount.to_f - xvaziri.paid.to_f %>

    <% color = @balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>

    <td class="col-1 <%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(@balance.abs, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>
</tr>
```

Running balance outside the table body;

```
<center><p><b><%= number_to_currency(@balance, :unit => 'AED ', :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></b></p></center>
```

How do I retrieve the same formatting for the running balance in both the places.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a class to your `<p>` and conditionally assign a value based on `@balance`; something like:

```
<p class="<%= @balance >= 0 ? "balance_pos" : "balance_neg" %>">
  <b><%= number_to_currency(@balance, :unit => 'AED ', :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></b>
</p>
```

And then in your `application.css`

```
.balance_pos {
  color: green;
}

.balance_neg {
  color: red;
}
```

to remove the '-' just call `.abs` on `@balance` as you did in the table.